# LightSwitch HTML - sava data on WCF RIA DataWorkspace, call CRUD methods on DataService

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-ria-services, ria, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have the follow problem: I have a DataSource (GiriDataServiceData2) coming from a WCF RIA service using POCO entities.

In a screen based on the table/query of this DataSource I make some modification and I'd like to apply those.

myapp.applyChanges seems not useful and I expected that LS call my CRUD WCF RIA methods..

Some one can help me? THANKS!!

Here an example of my CRUD Methods

```
 #region CRUD methods Briciola

    [Query(IsDefault = true)]
    public IQueryable<BriciolaEntity> GetBriciolaData()
    {
        // Todo            
        return null;
    }

    [Query(IsDefault = false, IsComposable = false)]
    public IQueryable<BriciolaEntity> GetBriciolaDataByIdTappa(int? IdTappa)
    {
        // Todo
        return BuildTappa(IdTappa.Value)[0].Briciole.AsQueryable();            
    }

    public void UpdateBriciolaEntity(BriciolaEntity giro)
    {
        // Todo
    }

    public void InsertBriciolaEntity(BriciolaEntity giro)
    {
        // Todo
    }

    #endregion
```

Comment: OK, my error..I should use myapp.activeDataWorkspace.GiriDataServiceData2.saveChanges();

Comment: Note that you'll also need the default query, in order to make the update functions work.
LS will first fetch your record by using the default query. This is done for concurrency checking

Comment: Thanks chielus, but I call end use only the GetBriciolaDataByIdTappa method..here I cannot post other images until 8 hours, pleas see this issue: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f07a7da9-d7d7-44ea-9494-d389f7408dc1/sava-data-on-wcf-ria-dataworkspace?forum=lightswitch&prof=required

Comment: Chielus can you help me to understand why I call a query that returns a entity with 3 childs (Tappe) and on the client I see 0 childes..maybe the Association in the POCO class is wrong??

Comment: [Include]
        [Association("AssocTappe", "IdGiro", "ParentId", IsForeignKey = false)]        
        public IQueryable<TappaEntity> Tappe { get; set; }